How to create an excel sheet (XLSX) using NPOI and add it to Multiple Excel files?
I have to create an Excel sheet detail in memory stream, and we have to copy it to multiple excel files.
IWorkbook wb,wb1,wb3 = new XSSFWorkbook();

XSSFSheet sheet1 = new XSSFSheet();

//Or
//ISheet sheet1 = new XSSFSheet();


IRow row =sheet1.CreateRow(0) ;
ICell cell = row.CreateCell(0);

cell.SetCellValue("Test");

//I Want to Add it like below. 
//Below Code is showing Compiler Error. 
wb.CreateSheet(sheet1);
wb1.CreateSheet(sheet1);
wb2.CreateSheet(sheet1);

Is there any way to create a sheet in Memory and add it to multiple workbook?

Below Code is showing Compiler Error - what error? Copy‘Paste it in your question
